# How to pass a Function as parameter without using delegates in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a code to write in a database table that I don't know in advance. When inserting a new row, some data need to have a "dynamic" default value. I'm writing a function to do that.

The code is aimed to be very generic. So I created an object called DefaultValueType

```
Public Class DefaultValueType
    Public FieldName As String
    Public DefaultValue As [Delegate]
    Public Sub New(ByVal _FieldName As String, ByVal _DefaultValue As [Delegate])
        Me.FieldName = _FieldName
        Me.DefaultValue = _DefaultValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

I create the new rows with a function like that:

```
Public Sub CreateNewRows(ByVal DefaultValues As List(Of DefaultValue))
    'Do some staff
    '...

    For i = 0 To DefaultValues.Count - 1
        '... do some staff

        'Default value of the row
        NewRow.Item(DefaultValues(i).FieldName) = DefaultValues(i).DefaultValue.DynamicInvoke()
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that when I create new DefaultValues I use

```
Dim X as new DefaultValue("ID",AddressOf(SomeFunction))
```

And I'm getting the error: 'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'System.Delegate' because type 'System.Delegate' is declared 'MustInherit' and cannot be created.

I can solve this issue by creating a delegate. But the code is aimed to fill default values of any type, so I have to create many delagates and write very long lines of "Select Case"

```
Public Delegate Function LongOutputFunction() As Long
Public Delegate Function StringOutputFunction() As String
Public Delegate Function BooleanOutputFunction() As Boolean
```

Does anyone have an Idea about how to pass a Function as parameter without using delegates ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a [Func(Of TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you detail that please ?

Comment: declare defaultvalue as taking a Func(of TResult) instead of definting you own values and use a generic object instead of doing dynamicly

Comment: @user1937198 post this as an answer instead.